# Copy and pasting between host and VM

Tags: macos, virtualization, copy-paste, virtualbox

I have a host machine running OS X 10.9.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.12 VM running Windows 7. I want to copy and paste between the host machine and the VM. By default copy-pastes don't seem to be transferable between machines. How can I do this?

There were some similar questions but using Linux/VMWare but the solutions have been specific to the VM in use.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's not by default. If you have installed [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html), then you can do this:

1. Start the VM
2. Go to `Machine > Settings` in the file menu.
3. Go to the `General` tab, then `Advanced`.
4. Set the `Shared Clipboard` setting to `Disabled`, `Guest to Host`, `Host to Guest` or `Bidirectional`.

Comment: Waitaminnit -- are you saying that Guest Additions are now available for OS X?  If so, where do I get them?

Comment: @fearless_fool click the link to guest additions in the answer :)

Comment: That's exactly my point: the docs specifically state that Guest Additions are NOT available for OS X (as specified in the OP). Am I missing something?

Comment: @fearless_fool It worked for me when I wrote this answer. I think what I did was the instructions directly after `4.2.1.1. Installation` at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows, where it says `On Mac OS X hosts, you can find this file in the application bundle of VirtualBox. (Right click on the VirtualBox icon in Finder and choose Show Package Contents. There it is located in the Contents/MacOS folder.)` http://i.stack.imgur.com/Obz5K.png

Comment: Bingo!  And there it is.  Thank you for the enlightenment.

Comment: It was a simple menu command for me: When running the VM, select `Devices`->`Insert Guest Additions CD Image`. This popped up a prompt in my VM to install them.

Comment: I wish virtual machine would somehow warn you to install the guest additions, I had no idea..

Comment: Is there anything else II have to do? I have GE installed and everything up to date yet when I try to copy things into Ubuntu from OSX I am getting nothing.

Comment: @ConstantFun AFAIK you shouldn't have to do anything other than enable it :/ Are you sure you've got the right direction set in settings? (eg bidirectional?)

Comment: I too have done all the above and still cannot paste.